# How to document python module using reStructuredText?

Tags: python, documentation, docstring, pep

I want to know how is the correct way to document a python module using reStructuredText format. [In PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/) there is a general description but no explanation about format for module documentation.

Comment: maybe you should use [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) to generate documentation: [Style guide for Sphinx-based documentations](https://documentation-style-guide-sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: What is the main difference between reStructuredText and Sphinx?

Comment: Sphinx generates documentation based on the reStructuredText you've decorated your API with.

Comment: reStructuredText is only file/data format - like HTML, markdown, etc. Sphinx is tool which can get all docstrings from Python code and generate documentation as HTML, PDF, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A reStructuredText based documentation of Python modules can also be generated with **GenPackageDoc**, that can be found here:

https://pypi.org/project/GenPackageDoc/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34616171)